# Where to obtain trusted certificate for my applet?

Tags: java, security, applet, certificate

I have a small company with website, that I'd like to make more interesting by adding there applet. I've prepared it already, and when launched from eclipse it works correctly. However when it is launched as an applet, from website I have a warning that it is not trusted and cannot run it without adding my page to java exceptions.
And here the fun begins. I'd like to have my applet signed in order to allow customers use it without any changes in their java configuration. I'm not planning to make more applets, or any other code that would need signing, so I don't really need to buy expensive certificates.
I've tried self-signing, however according to Java 7 policies it is not enough to run an applet.
I've also wanted to obtain free OpenSource Code certificate from Certum.eu, however the link doesn't work anymore.
CACert is also not an option, as I've heard that it is not trusted in all browsers...
Is there any way I could sign my applet with no harm to my wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to an open source certificate is CACert which is however not supported in [all browsers](http://wiki.cacert.org/InclusionStatus). [Thawte](https://www.certs4less.com/codesigning.html) and [Certum](https://sklep.unizeto.pl/ankieta/form.php) seem to have stopped offering free certificates for open source projects. (If you really want to know write an email to Certum why the link is dead)

The only thing I know of currently is [GlobalSign](https://www.globalsign.com/ssl/ssl-open-source/).